# Set a column equal to a count in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to set a column equal to the number of times the values occurs in a table, but running into issues when I try to store that as a column. What am I missing?

Goal

```
   id col1 count
  --------------
   1   a    3
   2   a    3
   3   a    3
   4   b    2
   5   b    2
```

I've tried:

```
select count(col1) as repidck 
from [User] u 
group by u.id
```

which works by itself, but when I try to set a column I get

```
update [User] 
set [count] = (select count(col1) as repidck 
               from [User] u 
               group by u.id)
```

Error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: You need to correlate your subquery... WHERE u.id = user.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery.  One way is:

```
update u
    set [count] = (select count(col1) from [User] u2 where u2.id = u.id)
    from [User] u;
```

But I would probably use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select u.*, count(u.col1) over (partition by u.id) as new_count
      from [User] u
     )
update toupdate
    set [count] = new_count;
```

Note:  `count` and `user` are lousy names for identifiers because they conflict with SQL keywords.

Comment: 'toupdate' doesnt exist for me. Do I need to declare it as a temp table or something?

Comment: @Rilcon42 . . . The CTE declares it.

Answer (score 0):

```
update [User] u1
set [count] = (select count(*) 
               from [User] u2 
               where u1.col1 = u2.col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would typically approach this by creating a `FROM` clause that calculates the data I want, then join it back into the original table.

```
UPDATE [user]
SET [count] = repidck
FROM
    [user]
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT col1, COUNT(*) repidck
        FROM [user]
        GROUP BY col1
    ) counts
        ON counts.col1 = [user].col1
```

Hope this helps